# Find any used classes in a PHP file

Tags: php, regex

I want to find any used classes in a PHP file using regex.
For example, assume I have a file like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\MyNamespace;

use App\MyNamespace\Foo as FooNamespace;

class MyClass
{
    public function run()
    {
        (new FooNamespace\ClassFoo());
        FooNamespace\ClassBar::class;
        FooNamespace\ClassBaz::boot();
        FooNamespace\SubNamespace\ClassBaz::boot();
    }
}
```

Now I want to find `FooNamespace\ClassBar`, `FooNamespace\ClassBaz` and `FooNamespace\SubNamespace\ClassBaz`.

I tried `\w+(\\\w+)+(\(|:)` which seems to work on https://regex101.com/ but it seems there is a problem in `\\\w` when I use it in PHP.

```php
preg_match_all('/\w+(\\\w+)+(\(|:)/', $content, $classes, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)
```

How should I modify the regex to find what I want?

Comment: Can you show us your php code?

Comment: I edited the question and added my code.

Comment: `$re = '/\w+(?:\\\\\w+)*(?=:)/';` should work in your php code

Comment: Nice! It worked for classes ending with `:` but not for `(`.  Here `\\\\\w+` why you put 4  backslashes before '\w`?

Comment: That's fine, i already used 4 backslashes and i got my desired output. But I don't understand why I need to put 4 backslashes?

Comment: Please read about it, it has been answered in detail many times on SO

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I didn't understand using correctly how to use backslashes!
The answer is to use 4 backslashes instead of 2 as [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) mentioned in the comment.

So if you want to find classes, you need to use this regex: `\w+(\\\\\w+)+(\(|:)`